# Setting up encryption after debian wheezy install

Tags: linux, encryption, home

How do you set up encryption on your home dir after the debian wheezy install. I missed the part in the graphical install that sets that up for you. I am using the automatic partition on the whole of the Free space

Comment: I gave you instruction for encrypting yoru home directory below. If you wish to encrytp you entire installation, no other option but to re-install.

Answer (score 1):

First install ecryptfs-utils (it may already be installed)

```
sudo apt-get install ecryptfs-utils
```

then boot to recovery mode and as root run:

```
ecryptfs-migrate-home -u your_user_to_migrate
```

After the script runs, log out and log in as your user.

```
exit
```

You might also with to run:

```
ecryptfs-unwrap-passphrase
```

Enter your use password when prompted and save the information in a safe place in the event you need to perform data recovery.

Last you can delete the temp files / directories created by the migration script and reboot (technically you do not need to reboot).

Comment: thanks, is there also a way to do the same to the swap and everything else apart from the /boot. I think this is what is does by default in the installer